# Select2 with ajax in lravel 10 don´t work

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2-4

I am working with select2 v.4.1 and laravel 10
every time I try to make the query I do not get any information, it is not activating the ajax query either 
 in the error console only an error appears every so often saying 
Empty string passed to getElementById (),
verify that you were initializing the select as follows: 
`console.log($('.search-product').length);` 
and it gives me as a result 1

this is the js code

`$(document).ready(function() {`  
    `$('#search-product2222').select2({` 
        `ajax: {` 
            `type:'POST',` 
            `url: "{{route('search.product')}}",` 
            `dataType: 'json',` 
            `//quietMillis: 15,` 
            `data: function (params) {` 
                `console.log(params.term)` 
                `return {` 
                    `term: params.term,`
                    `type: 'public',`
                   `limit: 10`
                `};`
            `},` 
            `processResults: function (data, page) {` 
            `console.log('88');` 
                `if (data.results != null) {` 
                    `return {` 
                        `results: data.results` 
                    `};` 
                `} else {` 
                `console.log('94')`
                `return {results: [{id: '', text: 'No Match Found'}]};`
                `}`
            `}`
        `},`
    `})`
`});`

this is the code in the blade

`<select id="search-product2222" class="form-select"></select>`

and this is the function in the controller

`public function product(Request $request)` 
    `{` 
        `$query = $request->input('term');` 
        `$product = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")` 
                    `->orWhere('code', 'LIKE', "%$query%" )` 
                    `->get();` 
        `$formatted_products = $product->map(function ($product)` {
            `return ['id' => $product->id, 'text' => $product->name];`
        `});`
            return response()->json(['results' => $formatted_products]);`<br/>`     }`